# cordova-hot-code-push-plugin in mac error

Tags: cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

I use [cordova-hot-code-push-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-hot-code-push-plugin) to realize hot code push, and it's okay on android, but there is error on ios when using command `cordova run ios` as following:

```bash
CHCP plugin after prepare hook:
Failed to load iOS project file. Maybe your Cordova version is not supported?
```

the versions I use:

```bash
cordova 11.0.0
cordova-ios 6.2.0
Xcode 13.3
Build version 13E113
```

thx for any suggestions!